# How to find the order of floating point operations(additions), given a list of floats and the sum of the list

Tags: math, floating-point, reverse-engineering, combinatorics

### Introduction

Floating point operations are not associative.
This means if you have a list of floats, the sum you will get, depends on the order of the operations.

I am wondering whether someone already wrote an algorithm to find a combination of floating point additions which sum up to a given result.

### Problem

**Given**

```
arr = [ 0.13802005, -0.04358668, -0.02762653,  0.12191868, -0.00974631, 0.16959566, -0.02888574,  0.13568747](dtype=float32)
sum_of_floats =  0.45537661015987396
```

**Find**

Order of operations which result in the same value as **sum_of_floats**

#### Examples

Possible Solution

```
In[19]: ((arr[0] + arr[4]) + (arr[2] + arr[6])) + ((arr[3] + arr[7]) + (arr[1] + arr[5])).item()
Out[19]: 0.45537661015987396
```

Wrong Solution

```
In[24]: ((arr[0] + arr[1]) + (arr[2] + arr[3])) + ((arr[4] + arr[5]) + (arr[6] + arr[7])).item()
Out[24]: 0.45537659525871277
```

Another wrong solution

```
In[25]: (((((((arr[0] + arr[1]) + arr[2]) + arr[3]) + arr[4]) + arr[5]) + arr[6]) + arr[7]).item()
Out[25]: 0.45537659525871277
```

### Question

Is there an existing algorithm to find one/all possible solutions to this problem ?

Comment: This is the same as finding all the different ways to parethise an expression: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-balanced-parentheses/

Comment: There is also one different problem, and that is most of the time it is not guaranteed that the sum actually ends up as one of the parethised version. The guarantee is usually the the error does not exceed the error calculated from the parameters of the given floating point representation.,

Comment: I guess you could just brute-force through all possibilities. Maybe use reverse polish notation (i.e, `a b + c + d +` for `((a+b) + c) + d`, to `a b c d + + +` for `a + (b + (c+d))`). Perhaps there is a more clever way, but brute-forcing is just O(n²), so for reasonably-sized problems you should be fine.

Comment: Does this have some practical application?

Comment: @chtz: It's a lot slower than O(n²). This is the relevant sequence: https://oeis.org/A001147.  (See the comment that starts "a(n) is the number of distinct products ...")

Comment: @MarkDickinson Indeed, I overlooked that OP allowed to commute variables.

Comment: The `reverse-engineering` tag should be removed.  The question has nothing to do with reverse engineering.

Comment: @g_bor thank you. I'm having a look right now and will try to integrate it with floats. So it works for my problem. Regarding your second command, I don't really understand what you are saying can you eloborate a bit further ?

Comment: typo above i meant: *comment

Comment: @chtz Thank you for the hint with reverse polish notation. This is useful

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes I want to know how pytorch and numpy do it's summing. So I can build reproducible unit tests which compare two different neural network implementations (one in numpy one in pytorch). Also i was just wondering in general.

Comment: @KoKlA: Are you sure they are doing plain floating-point additions? They might be doing Kahan summations (using extra variables for more precision), reordering operands (sorting to add lesser magnitudes first, to reduce rounding errors), or other techniques.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The other route would be to look at the source but there are so many layers of abstraction that i wanted to avoid this. python -> c -> cuda .

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think so yes. Kahan requires more compute and therefore isn't used in pytorch or numpy as default. Also kahan isn't that suited for parallel computation which is heavily used in pytorch.

Comment: @fpmurphy I do not think it should be removed when you have a library or API call which does the summing for you and you want to know how it is doing this, then it's reverse engineering.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oh you were right they are using pairwise summation according to https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/7038 which also reduces error.

Comment: @KoKlA.  You have not specified a library or an API in your question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Though as far as I can tell from the pseudocode this is still just plain additions no extra variables.

Comment: @KoKlA: I do not think “pairwise summation” is a precisely defined term in general, although maybe they define it somewhere in their source, but it suggests to me they might be adding pairs of the original numbers, then adding pairs of those first sums, then adding pairs of those second sums and so on, essentially like a binary tree.

Comment: @fpmurphy Yes I wanted to keep it general. As I was also wondering in general . For the specific APIs (numpy and pytorch) I might create a different question though.

Comment: If you want to reverse-engineer how a certain implementation is summing arrays (and assuming it does not do anything fancy like sorting or Kahan summation), you could start with an array of `{1e99, -1e99, 1, 1, ...}` and shift the `-1e99` until none of the `1`s gets rounded away. Then you know which number gets added to the first element first. Proceed with `0, 1e99, -1e99, 1, 1, ...}` etc

Comment: @chtz oh yes, that's way better thank you !